# numpy: test that the array is almost 0

Tags: numpy, test-suite

To check that the array is almost 0, I use [`np.testing.assert_almost_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal.html):

```
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(v, np.zeros(len(v)))
```

This allocates a new vector just for the test.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass an array, a scalar is enough and numpy will broadcast:

```
v = np.array([0, 0.0000001])

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(v, 0)
```

As a bonus, this works with any number of dimensions.